# Generating a binary probability combination function

Tags: pr.probability

I have been trying to develop a function that can combine two probabilities using the rules:

$f(x,y)\in C^\infty (\mathbb{R}^{2})$

$f(x,y)=f(y,x)$

$f(x,1-x)=\frac{1}{2}$

$f(1-x,1-y)=1-f(x,y)$

$f(0,x)=0$

$f(x,\frac{1}{2})=x$

$f(x,1)=1$

$f_x(x,y)\geq 0$

$f(0,1)$ does not exist. All other points $(x,y) \in [0,1]\times [0,1]$ should be defined.

I do not believe any polynomial solution exists. I am wondering if a solution exists and if so how to find it. I believe that if such a solution exists, it would be of the form, or of a similar form, to
$a+b^{c}$
where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are linear or quadratic functions of $x$ and $y$, and maybe quartic at worst.

The intent of this function is to make an iterative solver of the game binario based solely on probability. I am aware that this function would not be fully able to solve the game but I am still interested in its existence.

Comment: Why do you believe the form is $a+b^c$?

Comment: Amir Sagiv - It is one of the only other infinitely differentiable functions that there is, along with that i could have b reach infinity near when x or y near 0 or 1 and given the right values for a and c, it would work for those. lim y->0+ f(x,y)=0+(1/y)^(x-1), lim y->1- f(x,y)=1-(1/(1-y))^(-x). Note that these would just be rough estimates, and also note the - in the second equation.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the term "generating function" -- see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function . So, the tag generating-functions seems misplaced. Also, what do you mean by "a binary probability combination function"? As far as I know, there is no such thing. Or is this phrase supposed to mean "the joint cumulative distribution function of a pair of real-valued random variables" -- see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Joint_cumulative_distribution_function ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want all your conditions to hold for all real $x,y$, then that is impossible. Indeed, if $f(x,1-x)=\frac12$ and $f(0,x)=0$ for all real $x$, then $0=f(0,1)=f(0,1-0)=\frac12$, which is a contradiction.

---

Also, the identities $f(0,x)\equiv0$ and $f(x,1)\equiv1$ contradict each other, regarding the value of $f(0,1)$.

Other contradictions can be obtained using the symmetry $f(x,y)\equiv f(y,x)$.

---

Looking back at the title of your post about "a binary probability combination function", let me make a wild guess: You actually want your function $f$ to be the joint cumulative distribution function (cdf) of some pair $(X,Y)$ of real-valued random variables (r.v.'s), right? If so, then your conditions present much more trouble for $f$ than just being impossible to define at the two points, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Indeed, if $f$ were the joint cdf of a pair $(X,Y)$ of r.v.'s, then we would have
$$P(1/2<X\le1,1/2<Y\le1)=f(1,1)-f(1,1/2)-f(1/2,1)+f(1/2,1/2) \\ 
=1-1-1+1/2=-1/2<0,$$
which contradicts the nonnegativity of any probability.

Comment: That said, $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$ (and surrounding neighborhoods) should be the only problems.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this, I should have included it in my original post. I want a value of 0 for either x or y to mean that it is certain that the value is 0, while a value of 1 for x or y means that it is certain it is 1. Since those cannot intersect outside of a contradiction, it would not matter for my application. It is almost desirable that it be undefined at f(0,1)

Comment: What other points would the function be in contradiction at?

Comment: @opfromthestart : So that not to waste the time and effort of people who try their best to help you, I do think you should make your post as clear as possible from the very beginning, with all exceptions and all quantifiers (such as "for all real $x\ne1$") in place, and without using statements such as  "those cannot intersect outside of a contradiction", to which it seems impossible to attach a meaning.